# How to include SDL library in my VS 2010 project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

I encountered a problem with linking and distributing libraries in Visual Studio 2010. What I want to do:

- Link my project with SDL and use its headers
- Keep SDL somewhere in my project directory, so when I clone it from source control on another machine, I won't have to install any additional library.

My attempts so far:

- Google points to tutorials like this one : [Lazy Foo Productions](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php), but it doesn't do what I want because SDL is placed outside project directory.
- When I copy SDL to solution directory and add it via Project->Properties->Linker.... It works, but project settings now contain absolute path to library directory, so I guess it won't compile on other machine.

What should I do? SDL is just a example here, I'd like to know how to solve such problem with any library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Project->Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` to specify new directory where the linker to look up for libraries (it can use relative path)

You can use `Project->Properties->C++->General->Additional Include Directories` to specify where to look for the headers.

Comment: `It can use relative path` - relative to where?

Comment: to the project directory. Though if you have some problems (I don't why you should but still) you can use `$(ProjectDir)\path\to\libraries_or_includes` or `$(SolutionDir)\path\to\libraries_or_includes` It will replace `$(ProjectDir)` with your project dir and `$(SolutionDir)` with your solution directory